# Python Category Tree/Leaf Class Keeping Variable State

Tags: python, django, tree

I have the following class for a Category/Leaf implementation:

```
class CategoryMapper():
    @staticmethod
    def get_tree():
        categories = []
        tree_categories = Category.objects.filter(parent_id__isnull = True) 
        for tree_category in tree_categories:
            leaf_categories = CategoryMapper.get_leafs(tree_category)
            categories += leaf_categories

        return categories

    @staticmethod
    def get_leafs(tree_category, leaf_categories = [], depth = 0):
        if depth > 0:
            child_categories = Category.objects.filter(parent_id__exact = tree_category.id)
            if len(child_categories):
                depth += 1
                for sub_category in child_categories:
                    sub_category_name = ((depth - 1) * '-') + sub_category.category
                    leaf_categories.append([sub_category.id, sub_category_name])

                    return CategoryMapper.get_leafs(sub_category, leaf_categories, depth)
            else:
                return leaf_categories
        else:
            leaf_categories.append([tree_category.id, tree_category.category])
            depth += 1

            return CategoryMapper.get_leafs(tree_category, leaf_categories, depth)
```

I have the following date:
ID|Category|Parent ID
1|Test 1|None
2|Test 1 Child|1
3|Test 2|None

When I run it (CategoryMapper.get_tree()) I get:

```
[[1, u'Test 1'], [2, u'-Test 1 Child'], [1, u'Test 1'], [2, u'-Test 1 Child'], [3, u'Test 2']]
```

When I run it again, I get:

```
[[1, u'Test 1'], [2, u'-Test 1 Child'], [3, u'Test 2'], [1, u'Test 1'], [2, u'-Test 1 Child'], [1, u'Test 1'], [2, u'-Test 1 Child'], [3, u'Test 2'], [1, u'Test 1'], [2, u'-Test 1 Child'], [3, u'Test 2']]
```

Its like the categories variable in get_tree() is having its state kept every time the for loop is ran when going through the tree_categories. What am I doing wrong? Why is it keeping state like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, you need to avoid using mutable objects as default arguments to functions, like []. Instead, just define `get_leafs` like this:

```
def get_leafs(tree_category, leaf_categories = None, depth = 0):
    if leaf_categories is None:
        leaf_categories = []
    …
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I will get up-to-speed on mutable objects now.